# Continuous map on $\ell^p$ and Compact subset

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $ 1 \leq p < \infty $.

Consider the normed space $\ell^p$ . Show that the following map is continuous. $$T(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n,\ldots) = (x_1^2,x_2^2,\ldots,x_n^2,\ldots) $$

Now  let $p=1$. Consider $$A = \{x \in \ell^1 : |x_k| \leq \frac 1k \; \forall k \}$$

Determine if $T(A)$ is compact.

This is a question I found in a book and so it's missing a few details. I'm assuming here that $T$ is defined as map from $\ell^p$ to itself.

I tryed proving continuity by somehow going after Lipschitz but I didnt get very far.

As for the set $A$ , I know that the set is not compact in $\ell^1$ . I'm not sure how to determine if the Image is compact though.

Thoughts?

Comment: For continuity, did you try to prove it using convergent sequences? For the compactness, you may want to try proving that every sequence in T(A) has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: $T$ is not Lipschitz continuous on all of $l^1$, for example if  $v(n,1)=n$ and $v(n,m)=0$ for $1<m$ and $y(n)=(v(n,m))_{m\in N}$ then  $||y(n)-0||=n$ and  $||T(y(n))-T(0)||=n^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for convergence: $$\|T(x) - T(y)\|^p = \sum_j |x_j - y_j|^p |x_j + y_j|^p
\le \|x - y\|^p \sup_j |x_j + y_j|^p$$

Hint for $T(A)$: a sequence in $T(A)$ has a subsequence that converges elementwise. Does it converge in norm?